# 'node modules' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

can someone help me using this library
http://webxcerpt.github.io/openCPQ/doc/tutorial.html

I tried to follow all mentioned steps in this tutorial but When I used:
node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress --production

it showed me the error:
'node modules' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Can you please help me with this?

node version: v12.18.3
npm version: 6.14.6
OS: Windows 8.1 64bits

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in windoze, it would be `node_modules\.bin\webpack --progress --production` on the command line - note ... \ instead of / because microsoft

Comment: node_modules is a folder so make sure you are one level above that path to execute this command.